# Syntax error when Calling function inside function in Ocaml

Tags: ocaml

I am getting a Syntax error when **calling** the function **f** and **g** inside **lp** and assigning them to **y** and **z**

```
let lp m = 
    let y = f m in
    let z = g y (List.length y) m;
```

Here's my full code:

```
open Printf
open Format

let regraUm m = m/2
  
let regraDois m = ((m / 10) mod 10) * (m mod 10)

let regraTres m = 42

let f m =
    let list = ref [] in
        if ((m mod 2) = 0) then list := 1::!list;
        if ((m mod 3) = 0) || ((m mod 4) = 0) then list := 2::!list;
        if ((m mod 5) = 0) then list := 3::!list;
        !list


let g list len m =
    let res = ref [] in
    for i = 0 to (len-1) do
        let regra = List.nth list i in
            if (regra = 1) then res := (m - (regraUm m))::!res;
            if (regra = 2) || ((m mod 4) = 0) then res := (m - (regraDois m))::!res;
            if (regra = 3) then res := (m - (regraTres m))::!res;
    done;
    !res


let lp m = 
    let y = f m in
    let z = g y (List.length y) m;
```

Syntax Error:

```
ocamlopt regras.ml -o r
File "regras.ml", line 33, characters 4-4:
Error: Syntax error
```

**f** and **g** work properly when used outside of a function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A let binding need some expression to be attached after an `in`, which in your case doesn't exist. In this case your code would work either adding `z` as expression or removing the binding leaving just the expression.

```ml
let lp m = 
    let y = f m in
    let z = g y (List.length y) m in
    z
```

Or this

```ml
let lp m = 
    let y = f m in
    g y (List.length y) m
```